# Unintended I/O interruptions in multithreaded programs

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok, so I've been getting some issues getting my code to work, so I made a simplified version of my program to figure out what was going on, but I am still puzzled.

Here's the program:

This is the server code:

```
public class Server{

    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket connection;
    private DatagramSocket server_socket;
    String compString = "";
    public static List<String> messages = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
    public static List<DatagramPacket> packets = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<DatagramPacket>());


    public Server()
    {               
    }

    public void startRunning()
    {
            try
            {
                server_socket = new DatagramSocket(9876);       
                receiveAndSend();               
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception caught");
            }
    }

    public void receiveAndSend()
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try{
                while(true)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[3000];
                    DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                    server_socket.receive(request);   
                    String mess = new String(request.getData());                        
                    synchronized(messages)
                    {
                        if(!messages.contains(mess) && !packets.contains(request))
                        {                               
                            addMessage(mess);
                            addPacket(request);                             
                            System.out.println("added: " + mess);               
                        }               
                    }                       
                }
                }catch(Exception e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception caught");
                }           
            }            
        };  
        thread1.start();            
        Thread thread2 = new Thread() 
        {    
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(6000);         
                        System.out.println("the list contains");                            
                        synchronized(messages)
                        {
                            compString = "";                    
                            for (String st : messages)
                            {       
                                System.out.println(st);
                            }
                            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");    

                            if(!messages.isEmpty())
                            {

                                System.out.println(messages.size());                                    

                                for(int i=0; i< messages.size(); i++)
                                {                   
                                    compString += messages.get(i);
                                    compString += "-";

                                }                                                           
                            }                               
                        }                               
                        System.out.println("final string is:" + compString + "\n");                     
                        for(DatagramPacket pack: packets)
                        {
                            try
                            {                   
                                InetAddress add = pack.getAddress();
                                int port = pack.getPort();

                                byte[] tbuffer = compString.getBytes();
                                DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(tbuffer, tbuffer.length, add, port);
                                server_socket.send(reply);
                            }catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Exception caught");
                            }

                        }    
                    }                   

                }catch(Exception e) 
                {

                }           
            }            
        };              
        thread2.start();    
    }

    public synchronized void addMessage(String mess)
    {       
        messages.add(mess);
    }
    public synchronized void addPacket(DatagramPacket packet)
    {
        packets.add(packet);
    }       
}
```

This is the client code:

```
public class Client {

    public String message;
    public int port;
    public int server = 9876;

    public void Client(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void startRunning()
    {
            serverStart();   
    }


    public void serverStart()
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread() 
        {     
            public void run() 
            {
                try{                        
                    DatagramSocket ssocket = new DatagramSocket(port);              
                while(true)
                {                   
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        byte [] m =message.getBytes();
                        InetAddress hhost = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"); //won't be always localh

                        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(m, m.length, hhost, server);                        
                        ssocket.send(request);

                        System.out.println("sending: " + message + "\n");

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
                        DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);                       
                        ssocket.receive(reply);

                        String receivedString = new String(reply.getData());

                        System.out.println("receivedString : " + receivedString);
                        if(receivedString != null && !receivedString.isEmpty())
                        {


                        }                   

                }
                }catch(Exception e) 
                {
                     System.out.println("Exception caught");
                }


            }
        };

        thread1.start();        

    }

    public String[] convertStringToArray(String tstring)
    {
        tstring.trim();

        String[] sarray = tstring.split("-");

        return sarray;
    }

}
```

You need these 3 to run the code:

```
public class ServerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Server s = new Server();
        s.startRunning();
    }

}

public class ClientTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client myclient = new Client();
        myclient.message = "Hello";
        myclient.port = 6965;
        myclient.startRunning();            

    }

}

public class ClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client myclient = new Client();
        myclient.message = "Kitty";
        myclient.port = 6646;
        myclient.startRunning();

    }        

}
```

I get the following output when I run:

```
added: Helloadded: Kittythe list contains
Hello2
final string is:Hellothe list contains
Hello
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2
final string is:Hello
the list contains
Hello
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

The problem is that: 1) The println sometimes gets interrupted and never runs, in the above output we can see that the line !!!!!!!!!!!!!! doesn't get printed out sometimes.
2) Some elements in the Arraylist doesn't get added or doesn't get printed.

I did try to put synchronized blocks everywhere, but it didn't seem to work and various other things that didn't help either.

Comment: (Off-topic, but related to getting better help): one blank line is enough whitespace - for better help, format your code nicely so we can read it.

Comment: `catch(Exception e)
            {

            }` is the problem. Just think about it…

Comment: no, it's not. I removed the print statements inside the catch block because I wanted to see if the behavior would somehow change. I've added the statements back a while ago and the output didn't change at all.

Comment: I added the print statements so that you can run it yourself and see it has nothing to do with the lack of print in the catch.

Comment: Downvoted for posting a poorly formatted mess and for not fixing it when asked. I just deleted 863 redundant whitespace characters and there could have been more. Don't write code like this. -1

Answer (score 0):

You're not serializing/deserializing your Strings correctly.

In your server you should specify the byte range of the data to take from the receiving buffer, and the encoding that the client used:

```
String receivedString = new String(reply.getData(), 0, reply.getLength(), "UTF-8");
```

In your client you should specify an encoding to use to serialize the String:

```
byte[] m = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Also, `DatagramPacket.equals()` only does reference comparison (i.e. it will only return true if when passed a reference to itself; it's not comparing the data in the other packet with its own), so `!packets.contains(request)` will always be true.

Comment: But it seems that the arraylist only contains 1 element, is the thread getting interrupted or something or is it just the I/O, because I am not getting any exception?